# Time zone configuration of multiple PostgreSQL instances on single host?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I'm running PostgreSQL as a Docker container (`postgres:14.2`).

I see the system timezone is set to `UTC`.

I'm trying to understand the impact of changing the `timezone` config of PostgreSQL.

- If I ran multiple instances on a single host, and changed the timezone for 1 instance (via `.conf`), would all other instances be affected?
- Or can each instance's timezone be configured separately?
- Can a separate timezone be configured per schema?

Output from Docker container:

```
postgres@55f0148bcd87:~$ date
Mon Nov 28 17:55:35 UTC 2022
```

```
postgres@55f0148bcd87:~$ cat /etc/timezone
Etc/UTC
```

`cat data/postgresql.conf`:

```
timezone = 'Etc/UTC'
```

Comment: 1) From here [postgresql.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT): *TimeZone (string) Sets the time zone for displaying and interpreting time stamps. The built-in default is GMT, but that is typically overridden in postgresql.conf; initdb will install a setting there corresponding to its system environment. See Section 8.5.3 for more information.* 2) It per instance so each will have it own `timezone`.

Comment: You should read this [DateTime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) *8.5.1.3. Time Stamps* to see what this means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each cluster (instance) is independent and has its own settings. The setting of `timezone` for a cluster is the default value for connections to databases in the cluster, but each database session should override that setting with the value for the time zone that applies to that individual database session.